# Adding an ISAPI handler to IIS 7/8 -- 404.17 -- The requested content appears to be a script and will nto be served by the static file handler

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am trying to register a 32 bit ISAPI dll on my IIS 8 (7 Would work too!) machine.

I've installed the ISAPI and CGI extensions to IIS, I've added my DLL to the ISAPI Restrictions in IIS for the server.

I have added the following Module Mapping:

Path: *.rpt
Module: IsapiModule
Executable path/to/my/dll
Name: Whatever

This never seems to run however, and I always get a "cant be served by the static handler".

This handler appears above my staticfile handler on my ordered list.

I've tried to make this as a script map, with similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I needed to do the following:

Set my Default App pool to 32 bit (and classic mode?) and ensure that Crystal was *NOT* loaded as a module (which I had erroneously done)